# What are the suggested controls for two lists for selecting items

Tags: asp.net, controls

I want to create a wap page that contains the following:

- Source list to choose from
- Distination list, contains check box for each item
- Move, Return buttons between the lists

What are the suggested asp.net controls for the list to appear with the same look simply?

I think I have these options:

- Listbox & CheckBoxList (The problem is they doesn't have the same look)
- Two ListView or GridView (They're a bit complitcated to work with with very simple task)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague on how these lists are behaving and interacting with each other.  However, you may not need ASP .NET controls to handle what you're trying to do.  There's [a lot you can do with lists of items](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists) on a web page using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: I'm just looking for the appropriate ASP.Net controls, there are many options and I'd know the best

Comment: @John: If you limit yourself to the standard ASP .NET controls then you limit yourself to their limitations.  Yes, a ListBox and a CheckBoxList don't have the same look.  They're different controls to do different things.  And yes, ListView and GridView controls seem like they'd result in some serious over-engineering for this task.  Alternatively, you could create a highly-customized UI in HTML (with some CSS and JS) to achieve the presentation you're looking for.  If you're doing web development, HTML+CSS+JS are pretty handy things to know.

Answer (score 0):

If the list aren't too long I would use two list boxes and two buttons in tbetween them.  One button would remove selected items and the other one would add.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I looked for a checked list for the distination list.